# thread cancellation points in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there a concept of thread cancellation points in c++ just like in POSIX. I personally felt it's very handful feature especially when terminating threads that got blocked when a blocking function is called(eg. socket `recvfrom` function).

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cancellation+site%3Acppreference.com&ia=web and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+thread+cancellation -- not an answer, but a suggestion where to start research.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct equivalent.

The closest thing is `std::jthread`'s [`std::stop_token`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token) since C++20 which is a voluntary mechanism with which you can define points in the thread function at which the thread can be requested to terminate. You can wrap standard library or platform-specific functions in that, but it won't help you to cancel a thread that is stuck in a blocking library/system call.

There is no standard mechanism to cancel a blocking thread or cancel a thread involuntary. But you can access `.native_handle()` of a `std::thread` or `std::jthread` to get a handle to the underlying platform-specific thread implementation and then use platform-specific features from that (although you probably need to check that they don't interfere with the `std::thread`/`std::jthread` implementation; all of this will be implementation-defined).